# Objective C. If text field is equal to something, i want the label to display a certain text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to programming. I created a `NSDictionary` and put 3 strings in there. my goal is to display a message in the label every time I type a food name in the text field. the code below won't change the text in the label. its almost as if nothing is happening. But when I do `NSLog`, it shows everything correctly. Any suggestions?

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {
   NSDictionary *foodList = @{
      @"Chicken":@"BBQ it, then eat it with sauce.",
      @"Steak":@"Buy steak sauce and eat it with pleasure..",
      @"Sushi":@"Sushi is raw fish, eew, still wanna eat that?",
   };
   NSString *foodTextField1 = self.foodTextField.text;
   NSString *foodLabel = self.foodLabel.text;
   for (NSString *foodName in foodList) {
      NSString *foodRecipe = foodList[foodName];
      if ([foodTextField1 isEqualToString:foodName]) {
         foodLabel = foodRecipe;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually assigning foodLabel.text to anything anywhere in your code. You need to add:

```
self.foodLabel.text = @"Something";
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
NSString *foodLabel = self.foodLabel.text;
```

places into your local variable `foodLabel` a reference to an `NSString` having the value of the current label. It **does not** make `foodLabel` another name (an alias) for `self.foodLabel.text`.

Later when you do:

```
foodLabel = foodRecipe;
```

you are changing the string `foodLabel` references, you are in no way effecting the value of `self.foodLabel.text`.

The first statement, declaring `foodLabel` and setting it is not required at all - you never use the current value of the label.

The second statement should be:

```
self.foodLabel.text = foodRecipe;
```

to set the value of the label.

HTH

Comment: It works now thanks. I also want to add another line to this code that doesn't seem to work for me
if ([foodTextField1 isEqualToString:foodName]) {
         foodLabel = foodRecipe;
}
else
self.foodLabel.text = @"This food does not exist.";

Comment: You have a loop with searches for a match and sets the label if it finds one. If you wish to set a default label if there is no match then (a) after finding a match inside the loop and setting the label you can execute a `return` statement to immediately exit the method; and (b) after (a) you will only finish the loop if no match is found so after the loop assign the default value to your label. HTH